# Google authentication in AspNetCore.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Starting to play around with AspNetCore.Identity, but cannot run simple example, always receive such exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to
>   handle the scheme: google

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // EF services
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>();

        // Identity services
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // MVC services
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter(), new IsoDateTimeConverter() };
        });
```

Configure.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication();
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxx",
            ClientSecret = "xxx",
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

AuthController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Auth", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
    }
```

Exception happened somewhere after `ChallengeResult` is returned.
Did I miss something?

Comment: I tried your code and it was redirected to google successfully(`ExternalLogin` was not called because of `AutomaticChallenge = true`). It seems there is another problem. I suspect  the exception may happen after google authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using both `app.UseIdentity()` and setting `AutomaticAuthenticate = true` on your google middleware to true. Identity sets cookie auth to AutomaticAuthenticate, and you can only have a single authentication middleware set as automatic, otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

You'll see in the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html) that when facebook is wired up it is **not** set to automatically authenticate.

Comment: I will mark it as correct answer, thanks. But my problem was after all your suggestions that I passed 'google' provider, not [G]oogle (capitalized), after I change it, it started to work :/